# Jinja template in for loop

Tags: templates, jinja2, tailwind-css

I have a jinja template, with 9 placeholders in a block of rows. Each block displays an output item from a Python for loop. Each subsequent output items should display in a vertically separated block. My design below.

Question: How do I populate the second and subsequent blocks, with the same placeholder names? That is, after block-1 is populated in the first instance, how do I (i) programmatically add another block and (ii) ensure that the output of the second loop goes into the second block?

I haven't started writing code because I am not clear of the workflow; some guidance will be helpful.
[image: Jinja template]

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a [CSS grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout) for this.

First, we establish the row and column tracks for the grid. From the looks of it, I see 6 equal grid columns, and 7 grid rows that I'll assume to be the height of their containing content.

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃Item 1••••••••│{{meta.item1}}••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••┃
┠──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┨
┃••••••••••••Item 2•••••••••••│••••••••••••Item-3•••••••••••│••••••••••••Item-4 ••••••••••┃
┠──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┨
┃••••••••{{meta.item2}}•••••••│••••••••{{meta.item3}}•••••••│••••••••{{meta.item4}}•••••••┃
┠──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┨
┃Item5•••••••••│{{meta.item5}}••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••┃
┠──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┨
┃Item6•••••••••│{{meta.item6}}••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••┃
┠──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┨
┃••••••••••••Item7••••••••••••│••••••••••••Item8••••••••••••│••••••••••••Item9• ••••••••••┃
┠──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┨
┃••••••••{{meta.item7}}•••••••│••••••••{{meta.item8}}•••••••│••••••••{{meta.item9}}•••••••┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

We can use the [`grid-template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template) CSS property to establish named areas of our grid, according to the grid drawn above:

```css
.my-grid {
  grid-template:
    "label1 value1 value1 value1 value1 value1"
    "label2 label2 label3 label3 label4 label4" 
    "value2 value2 value3 value3 value4 value4" 
    "label5 value5 value5 value5 value5 value5"
    "label6 value6 value6 value6 value6 value6"
    "label7 label7 label8 label8 label9 label9" 
    "value7 value7 value8 value8 value9 value9"
    / 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Then, loop when loop through the items, setting their `grid-area` (assuming desired Tailwind syntax due to the Tailwind tag on the post, and I'm using consistent labelling for the sake of brevity):

```
<dl class="grid my-grid">
  {% for item in meta %}
    <dt style="grid-area: label{{ loop.index }}">Item {{ loop.index }}</dt>
    <dd style="grid-area: value{{ loop.index }}">{{ item }}</dd>
  {% endfor %}
</dl>
```

This would render to something like:

```css
.my-grid {
  grid-template:
    "label1 value1 value1 value1 value1 value1"
    "label2 label2 label3 label3 label4 label4" 
    "value2 value2 value3 value3 value4 value4" 
    "label5 value5 value5 value5 value5 value5"
    "label6 value6 value6 value6 value6 value6"
    "label7 label7 label8 label8 label9 label9" 
    "value7 value7 value8 value8 value9 value9"
    / 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<dl class="grid my-grid">
  
    <dt class="border" style="grid-area: label1">Item 1</dt>
    <dd class="border" style="grid-area: value1">{{meta.item1}}</dd>
  
    <dt class="border" style="grid-area: label2">Item 2</dt>
    <dd class="border" style="grid-area: value2">{{meta.item2}}</dd>
  
    <dt class="border" style="grid-area: label3">Item 3</dt>
    <dd class="border" style="grid-area: value3">{{meta.item3}}</dd>
  
    <dt class="border" style="grid-area: label4">Item 4</dt>
    <dd class="border" style="grid-area: value4">{{meta.item4}}</dd>
  
    <dt class="border" style="grid-area: label5">Item 5</dt>
    <dd class="border" style="grid-area: value5">{{meta.item5}}</dd>
  
    <dt class="border" style="grid-area: label6">Item 6</dt>
    <dd class="border" style="grid-area: value6">{{meta.item6}}</dd>
  
    <dt class="border" style="grid-area: label7">Item 7</dt>
    <dd class="border" style="grid-area: value7">{{meta.item7}}</dd>
  
    <dt class="border" style="grid-area: label8">Item 8</dt>
    <dd class="border" style="grid-area: value8">{{meta.item8}}</dd>
  
    <dt class="border" style="grid-area: label9">Item 9</dt>
    <dd class="border" style="grid-area: value9">{{meta.item9}}</dd>
  
</dl>
```